# Line width in legend?

Tags: r, plot

I want to change the width of the line in the legend. Currently I have:

```
legend(-0.145, 25, c("(Gaussian) Kernel density","fitted normal distribution"),lwd=1.8, cex=0.8, 
   col=c("black","black"), lty=1:2)
```

lwd seems to change the text, but not the width of the line and of the dotted line, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

I think you're wrong, `lwd` sets the line widths in your legend :

Compare this (top plot) :

```
plot(rnorm(100)*13)
legend(-0.145, 25, c("(Gaussian) Kernel density","fitted normal distribution"),lwd=0.1, cex=0.8, 
   col=c("black","black"), lty=1:2)
```

With this (bottom plot) :

```
plot(rnorm(100)*13)
legend(-0.145, 25, c("(Gaussian) Kernel density","fitted normal distribution"),lwd=3, cex=0.8, 
   col=c("black","black"), lty=1:2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the argument of legend function `seg.len` for reduce the size of the legend.

Here an example:

```
    set.seed(55) # Set the seed of R‘s random number generator
    x <- runif(10, min=0, max=100) # Generating random numbers
    plot(x, type="l") # plot x as line
    legend("topright", "x", lty="solid") # add legend
```

[image]

And same code modifiying the `legend` function:

```
    plot(x, type="l")
    legend("topright", "x", lty="solid",seg.len=0.5) # modify length of the line in the legend
```

[image]